# How to blit "print" onto screen in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I’ve written a simple RPG battle system where if you input “y” you get to attack but if you input “n” the enemy attacks you. The inputs are temporary until I implement an attacking system but all the of the outputs are being shown in the command prompt. How do I blit the print onto a pygame window instead of having it show up in the command prompt.

Code for battle system:

```
heroHP = 1000

hero={'name' : 'Hero',
      'height':4,
      'lvl': 1,
      'xp' : 0,
      'reward' : 0,
      'lvlNext':25,
      'stats': {'str' : 12, # strength
                'dex' : 4, # dexterity
                'int' : 15, # intelligence
                'hp'  : heroHP, # health
                'atk' : [250,350]}} # range of attack values


boss1={'name' : 'Imp',
       'xp' : 0,
       'lvlNext':25,
       'reward' : 25,
       'stats': {'hp'  :400,
                'atk' : [300,350]}}


def level(char): # level up system
    #nStr, nDex, nInt=0,0,0
    while char['xp'] >= char['lvlNext']:
        char['lvl']+=1
        char['xp']=char['xp'] - char['lvlNext']
        char['lvlNext'] = round(char['lvlNext']*1.5)
        nStr=0.5*char['stats']['str']+1
        nDex=0.5*char['stats']['dex']+1
        nInt=0.5*char['stats']['int']+1
        print(f'{char["name"]} levelled up to level {char["lvl"]}!') # current level
        print(f'( INT {round((char["stats"]["int"] + nInt))} - STR {round(char["stats"]["str"] + nStr)} - DEX {round(char["stats"]["dex"] + nDex)} )') # print new statsm
        char['stats']['str'] += nStr
        char['stats']['dex'] += nDex
        char['stats']['int'] += nInt

from random import randint

def takeDmg(attacker, defender): # damage alorithm
    dmg = randint(attacker['stats']['atk'][0], attacker['stats']['atk'][1])
    defender['stats']['hp'] = defender['stats']['hp'] - dmg
    print(f'{defender["name"]} takes {dmg} damage!')
    if defender['stats']['hp'] <= 0:
            print(f'{defender["name"]} has been slain...')
            attacker['xp'] += defender['reward']
            level(attacker)
            if defender==hero:
                print("[ G A M E   O V E R ]")
                print('---------------------------')
                input('Press ENTER to quit. ')
                exit()
            else:
                hero['stats']['hp']=heroHP
            print('---------------------------')



def commands(player, enemy):
    while ((enemy['stats']['hp'])>0): # continue algorithm unless enemy is dead
        print('---------------------------')
        cmd = input(f'Do you want to attack {enemy["name"]}? y/n: ').lower()
        if 'y' in cmd:
            takeDmg(player, enemy)
            print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
            takeDmg(enemy, player)
        elif 'n' in cmd:
            print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
            takeDmg(enemy, player)
        else:
            break

commands(hero, boss1)
```

Code for window:

```
from pygame import *
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
saveState = False

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (30, 30, 30)
FONT = font.SysFont("Courier New", 20)


def Title():
    mouse.set_visible(1)
    clock = time.Clock()

    Text = Rect(70, 300, 500, 60)

    while True:
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit("Quit") # if X is pressed, exit program
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()


        screen.fill(WHITE)

        draw.rect(screen, GRAY, Text)

        Text1_surf = FONT.render(("Test"), True, WHITE)


        screen.blit(Text1_surf, Text)

        display.update()

        clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show any text in pygame window what you can do is first set the font

```
font_1 = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier New', 15)
                             #(font name,size)
```

Then create a variable and assign the values to it

```
this_sentence=font_1.render('Write text here',True,(0,0,0))
                                                  #(0,0,0 is rgb value for 
                                                   # text color)
```

Then

```
screen.blit(this_sentence,(x,y))
                       #(x,y are coordinates respective to your display 
                         #screen)
```

Comment: I’ve done that in the window test code, but what I was asking was that I already printed lines of text using the “print” command in the battle system code. My question was how would I take what was printed there and blit it into a small rectangle in my window.

Comment: You have to manually adjust x,y coordinates of multiple this_sentences instances and blit it on the screen, I made full game like this works fine

Comment: what you can do is call a function which after the hero dies, which blits the message on the whole screen